# BrowserSync reloads browsers before task has finished when using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-browser-sync

I have the following configuration for BrowserSync task:

```
"dev": {
    "files": [
        {
            "expand": true,
            "cwd": "<%= paths.src %>",
            "src": "**/*"
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "watchTask": true,
        "proxy": "<%= site.host %>",
        "injectChanges": true,
        "notify": {
            "styles": {
                "top": "auto",
                "bottom": "0"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

When I save some change to a file the reloading browser task is fired before the actual change has been done. See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7hV2.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You have just change 'files' property in JSON with 'bsFiles' and listen to changes in compiled files:

```
 "bsFiles": {
        "src": [
            "<%= paths.dest %>**/*",
            "<%= paths.twigs %>**/*"
        ]
    },
```